# how can i call carousel() an external javascript function into html file?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i call external java script file's function

- carousel()

  in HTML file?
  This is an automatic slideshow of pictures. how this java script function call into HTML file, so the slideshow display and run automatically? also pictures change after a short time .

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>PUCIT</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="slideshow" >
  <img class="slides" src="pic1.jpg">
  <img class="slides" src="pic3.jpg">
  <img class="slides" src="pic4.jpg">
  <img class="slides" src="pic5.jpg">
  <img class="slides" src="pic2.jpg">
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what/where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume js.js is the file in question , which contain the carousel().

The way you include the file into the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
```

means it have to be in the same folder as the html file.

The only thing you have to do to execute the function is to call it. Put this code before closing  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    carousel();
</script>
```